# Angular Server side rendering error HTMLCanvasElement.exports.nyi

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

> Error: NotYetImplemented
>       at HTMLCanvasElement.exports.nyi (C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:30071:9)
>       at C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:391458:34898
>       at C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:391458:35221
>       at C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:391458:45461
>       at Object. (C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:391458:47139)
>       at **webpack_require** (C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:20:30)
>       at Object.web-animations-js (C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:371112:18)
>       at **webpack_require** (C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:364897:30)
>       at Object../src/app/home/home.component.ts (C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:366546:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (C:\frontend_server_side_rendering\NewUIUX2nd\bbbcustomerui\dist\server.js:364897:30)

i am geeting this error angular 5 server side rendering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `<canvas>` element is not supported by the SSR DOM implementation yet
See: [angular/universal-starter#538 (comment)](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/538#issuecomment-365518693)

If you want to use it with Angular Universal add to your HTML:

```
<canvas *ngIf="isBrowser">
```

In your component in a **.ts** file like so:

```
import { Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

public isBrowser: boolean;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object, private renderer2: Renderer2) {
  this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
}
```

Read more about this on [Angular Universal "Gotchas"](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/gotchas.md)